# Classic ASP Vbscript Conditional Statement for Time() not giving correct results

Tags: time, vbscript, asp-classic, conditional-statements

im working on a simple Conditional statement in vbscript to check whether a time is earlier than another time. and its not working or making any sense. just using dates seem to work but i need to use time... which isnt working.

```
dim startDateStartTime, CurrentDateCurrentTime

                startDateStartTime = FormatDateTime("12:00:00 PM")
                    response.Write("The Course Starts at: ["&startDateStartTime&"]<br/>")

                CurrentDateCurrentTime = FormatDateTime("5:00:00 AM")
                    response.Write("The Current Time is: ["&CurrentDateCurrentTime&"]<br/>")


                if CurrentDateCurrentTime < startDateStartTime then

                    response.Write("The current time is less then the course start time. Keep Course open")

                else

                    response.Write("The current time is greater then the course start time. Close Course")

                end if
```

the output for this statement is:

**The Course Starts at: [12:00:00 PM]**

**The Current Time is: [5:00:00 AM]**

**The current time is greater then the course start time. Close Course**

which is clearly wrong because 5am is less than 12pm. i dont get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FormatDateTime() returns a string:

```
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(FormatDateTime("12:00:00 PM"))
>>
String
```

So your

```
if CurrentDateCurrentTime < startDateStartTime then
```

compares a string starting with "5" to a string starting with "1". You need to compare (variables of sub-type) Date(s).

Answer (score 0):

For comparing date/time you should use function DateDiff

```
DateDiff(interval, date1, date2, [firstdayofweek], [firstweekofyear])
```